# How do you translate: What things, then, will you do?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

How do you translate the following sentence:

> What things, then, will you do?

I am particularly doubtful of the translation of "things" here. Would we use *res*, *rei*?

Comment: Can you tell us some more context for this question? For example, do you mean a situation like at [the end of the movie _Rambo 2_](https://youtu.be/HIU2aJS9cuM?t=1m52s), or Lyndon Johnson being sworn in as President, or, say, fixing a broken cartwheel? Depending on the situation, a word for "things" may or may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is often a temptation to translate word-for-word; as the Romans used fewer words than we do, to express the same meanings, this can be frustrating. Here they might well have said: "quae facies?"; "actiones" would have been understood; "then" unnecessary as, by definition, it is referring to the future, leading to an alternative: "quae facias?" a pres. subj., "what (things) might/ would you do; or, even some imperative force--demanding to know as in "habeas corpus" a pres. subj., not: "you may have a body"; but "you HAVE a body". Jerky & clumsy to us; but, not them.

Answer (score 0):

The neuter plural of the Interrogative Pronoun is simplest.

'Then' can be translated in a number of ways:
*prorsum* means 'then,' 'next,'  'straightaway.'
*igitur* (usually placed second word) 'then,' 'therefore.'

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

> *Quas [actionēs] tum (ergo/igitur) faciēs (agēs)?*

*Tum* was the go to word for "then" in out Latin text books at school; *facere* means to do or make, while *agere* means do or drive. Actions might be the better word here than things, but I would rather leave it out. In such case use the pronoun, *Quae*.

Comment: I would honestly leave out things/actions out altogether, though.

Comment: Just one additional note. *Tum* fits if "then" is to be taken temporally, but something in the realm of *igitur* makes sense if "then" is drawing a logical consequence.

Comment: You would need to modify it to *quas actiones*, for agreement. But I really don't think *tum* or *actio* is appropriate at all.

Comment: Words in brackets are best left out. Words in parentheses are other words that might better fit. I would still prefer *Quae tum faciēs* or *Quae tum ages*

Answer (score 0):

*Rēs gestae*, literally "things accomplished", is the term for a record of an emperor's life achievements. Most famously, the funerary inscription of Augustus is called the *Rēs Gestae Dīvī Augustī*, the "Things-Accomplished of the Divine Augustus".

So if you want to use an explicit noun for "things", I would use the verb *gerō*, in reference to this:

> *Quās rēs igitur gerēs?*
>   What things are you going to accomplish, then?

However, I find it more idiomatic to leave out *rēs* altogether. In that case, I'd use the verb *agō*, a very general-purpose word for "do":

> *Quod igitur agēs?*
>   So what are you going to do?

You can also use *faciō* for "do" if you prefer; the differences aren't huge:

> *Quod igitur faciēs?*
>   So what are you going to do?